# Cut norm of a graphon

Tags: graph-theory, normed-spaces, random-graphs, graph-limits

A symmetric measurable function $W\colon [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ is called a *graphon*.

Another notion is the *cut norm* of a symmetric measurable function $W\colon [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$: $$|| W ||_{\square} = \sup\limits_{S,T\in\mathcal{L}([0,1])} \left|\iint\limits_{S\times T} W(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \right|$$
where $\mathcal{L}([0,1])$ is the set of all Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $[0,1]$.

My question is the following: if we take the cut norm of a graphon $W$, since $W\geq 0$, we have
$$ ||W||_{\square} =  \sup\limits_{S,T\in\mathcal{L}([0,1])} \iint\limits_{S\times T} W(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y $$
Furthermore, since $W$ is non-negative on the entire $[0,1]^2$, then its integral is exactly the volume under the graph of $W$, i.e. the measure of the set $\{(x,y,z) | x,y \in [0,1], 0\leq z \leq W(x,y) \} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. And this way, I believe that the quantity $ \iint\limits_{S \times T} W(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y$ will be the largest when $S=T=[0,1]$, which means that $||W||_{\square} = \iint\limits_{[0,1]^2} W(x,y) \ \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y $.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a graphon, or more generally for any nonnegative $W\colon [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ you are correct. However, even for graphons we are not just interested in the cut norm, but also the cut *metric*
$$
   \delta_{\square}(W_1, W_2) = \inf_{\varphi} \|W_1 - W_2^{\varphi}\|_{\square} 
$$
where $\varphi\colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ is a measure-preserving bijection and $W_2^{\varphi}(x,y) = W_2(\varphi(x), \varphi(y))$.

No doubt you will encounter this definition in more detail later; intuitively, $W_2^\varphi$ is a "relabeling" of $W_2$, and $\|W_1 - W_2^{\varphi}\|_{\square}$ is minimized when $W_2^{\varphi}$ is as similar to $W_1$ as possible.

However, the point for now is that even though $W_1$ and $W_2$ are both nonnegative, $W_1 - W_2^{\varphi}$ is not, and so in the computation of $\|W_1 - W_2^{\varphi}\|$ it is not necessarily best to take $S = T = [0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thoughts, @Misha Lavrov!  What I'm actually trying to figure out is how to compute the cut distance of two *actual* graphons. For instance, if we take the simple threshold graphs $G_n$, i.e. the graphs defined on the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ by connecting $i$ and $j$ if and only if $i+j \leq n$, and the graphon $W_{G_n}$ corresponding to it, it is pretty obvious that this graph will have the graphon $W= \chi_{\{ (x,y)\in [0,1]^2 \colon x+y \leq 1\}}$ (where $\chi_S $ is the indicator function of a set $S$) as its limit.

Comment: But it is not so obvious -- at least for me -- how to calculate $\delta_{\square}(W_{G_n}, W)$ for an arbitrary value $n\in\mathbb{N}$. As you mentioned, I need to find $\inf\limits_{\varphi} ||W_{G_n} - W^{\varphi}||_{\square}$, but, unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed with finding the optimal $\varphi$ and $S,T$ respectively. (obvoiously, the resulting value $\delta_{\square}(W_{G_n}, W)$ should tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$). Could you please give me some advice on this issue?

Comment: The $S,T$ are the hard part and I don't really have as much intuition for that, but in yoru case, the optimal $\phi$ should just be the identity: intuitively, $W_{G_n}$ and $W$ are already "ordered in the same way".

Comment: If I take $\varphi(x)=x$ (the identity), then $W_{G_n}-W$ is $1$ on $n$ small triangles along the diagonal and $0$ elsewhere, so it's a non-negative function, and thus $S=T=[0,1]$ would be the right choice, I reckon.

Comment: Shouldn't $W_{G_n} - W$ be negative along half of the other diagonal?

Comment: I don't think so. If we look at $W_{G_n}\colon [0,1]^2\to[0,1]$ as an $n\times n$ "matrix", more precisely the adjacency matrix if $G_n$, then if we divide $[0,1]$ to $n$ equal parts $a_i = [(i-1)/n, i/n]$ ($1\leq i \leq n$), then $W_{G_n}$ is going to be $1$ on all the sets (squares) $a_i \times a_j$ for which $i+j \leq n $ holds. This means it's 1 on the upper "triangle" of the matrix (with regard to the main diagonal), and on the main diagonal itself, while $W$ is 1 on that upper triangle as well, but it is 1 only on a domain half the surface of the small squares on the main diagonal.

Comment: I don't know if I've managed to describe it clearly, but it's worth imagining the pixel image of the two graphons.

Comment: As I understood the definition, we set the $a_i \times a_i$ squares to $0$ for every $i$.

Comment: (But it should not affect things in the limit either way. If all we want to prove is that $\delta_{\square}$ goes to $0$, we can just say that $W_{G_n} - W$ is $0$ outside a region of area $o(\frac1n$).)